# EF Core dotnet ef create migration failed

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

There is the following context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace InternetShop.DAL
{
    public sealed class InternetShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAdditInfo> ProductAdditInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Characteristics> ProductsCharacteristics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public InternetShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<InternetShopDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a migration, but I get the following error

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'InternetShopDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

UPDATE:
in my API project in Startup.cs in ConfigureServices there is the following code

```
    services.AddDbContext<InternetShopDbContext>(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["PostgreSql"]);
    });
```

I added the --verbose flag and got the following exception

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[InternetShop.DAL.InternetShopDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'InternetShop.DAL.InternetShopDbConte
xt'.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a connection string named `PostgreSql` in the project's appsettings.json? Are you running the command against the correct project? Please show us the actual command you are using too.

Comment: Yes, there is a connection string in the API project. The command is as follows: dotnet ef migrations add initmigration --verbose

Comment: whereabouts are you running the command? Is it in the InternetShop.DAL project folder or the API project?

Comment: Also, I have three projects:
InternetShop.Api
InternetShop.DAL
InternetShop.SiteApp

I call the command while in the InternetShop.DAL project folder

Comment: The DAL project should have no idea about appsettings.json and cannot therefore cannot find a connection string. Try adding the [`--startup-project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project) to your command line pointing at your API project.

Comment: Thx, it really helped. I didn't take into account such a simple thing, thank you for pointing me out

Answer (score 0):

phuzi pointed out a mistake to me. The command should look like this if you have separate ASP.NET and DAL projects (for me it looks like):

```
dotnet ef migrations add migrationname --startup-project ..\InternetShop.Api\InternetShop.Api.csproj
```

a package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design must also be installed in the startup project